# How to change initial tab bar selection programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

Having problems changing the initial tab bar selection on an application (i.e. the middle tab is selected on app launch rather than the leftmost tab). The app uses storyboards and the tab bar controller was added later on in development via the storyboard method.

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

the above code doesn't work (because I don't have a custom view controller connected to my tab bar, just the default UITabBarController):

Done some googling and looked at many different resources and haven't quite found a solution for an app that wasn't initially created using Apple's template Tab Bar Application.

Comment: Is this the initial view controller for the project or is it pushed from another view controller?

Comment: the tab bar controller is the initial view controller.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since this is the initial view controller, and is not a subclass, you need to set this in your appDelegate.

In AppDelegate.m, add the following to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Select the left-most tab of our initial tab bar controller:
    UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 0;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You're brilliant. Worked perfectly. Makes sense i'd have to do it in the AppDelegate because it's the initial view controller. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, in the situation where you need to do something similar and it is not the initial view controller, you would over-ride `prepareForSegue` in the view which is before the one being loaded and set it from there.

Answer (score 1):

`tabBar setSelectedItem:` try using this in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: that doesn't work because I don't have a specific view controller for my Tab Bar (with a viewDidLoad method). I don't have an outlet created for my tab bar. It's just the default created in Storyboards.

Comment: I added a view controller.h and .m and connected it with my TabBarController. I created a UITabBarController outlet and used selected index. and then tried what you said (creating a UITabBar outlet and using setSelectedItem) and still nothing :/