# How do I change the initial tab bar selection in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In trying to find a solution I came across this answer:

[ https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441200/4856759 ]

It seems to accomplish what I want it to, but in objective C:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBar.selectedIndex = 0;
```

How do I do this in swift? My first attempt returns an error:

> cannot convert the expression's type '$T4??' to type 'UITabBarController'

```
var tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController
tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure your rootViewController is a UITabBarController?

Comment: Is the rootViewController the same thing as initial view controller? If so then yes

Comment: It should be. I'll fire up a playground and see if i can replicate the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked for me! You just need to add `as! UITabBarController`:

```
var tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
```