# How do I set the default tab for tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to change default tab bar with storyboard. I don't want to use any swift/object-c code.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you explain your question?

Comment: I have 5 tabs in my tab controller. I want to change default selected value from 1 to 3.

Comment: I don't think theres anything in IB for that. Will have to do it in viewDidLoad I suspect.

Comment: Check this -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440884/how-to-change-initial-tab-bar-selection-programmatically

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma. Even google could not point me towards the right solution! But you did! 

Answer (score 8):

Do the following:

1. Select the Tab Bar Controller you want to change
2. Go to the Identity Inspector in the Utilities panel
3. Add a new "User Defined Runtime Attribute"
4. Set Key Path to "selectedIndex", Type to "Number", and Value to 2 (since you want the third tab (index starts at 0)

Comment: Failed to set (selectedIndex) user defined inspected property on (Skin_Craft.CustomTabBarController): Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle